# Prove that if an injection exists such that $f: A\to \mathbb{N}$, the set $A$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I know that since an injection, $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ exists, that $|A| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$. That's as far as I've gotten.

The definition for "countable" from my book states that "A set is considered countable if the cardinality of the set is a subset of the natural numbers, $|S| \subseteq \mathbb{N}$".

I'm not sure how to transition from the step I'm on (or if it's even right) to the part given in the definition.

Comment: Your definition of countability seems weird / wrong.

Comment: What is the definition of "the cardinality of $A$ is $S$"?

Comment: Usually cardinalities are defined as initial ordinals, in which case the definition here actually does make sense. But it's definitely weird and unhelpfully obscure to do things that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is an injection into the naturals, then clearly there's a bijection into a *subset of the naturals*, call it $B$, then since $f : A \to B$ is a bijection we have $|A| = |B|$, and since $B \subset \Bbb{N}$ we have $|A| = |B| \leq |\Bbb{N}|$, any set $B$ with the last relation is countable, thus $A$ is countable.

Comment: This made a lot more sense to me than most of the other things I've read online. Thanks!

Comment: @user148098 How delightful!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one way to prove this could be to work in reverse, i.e. if $\exists g:\Bbb N\to A$ where $g$ is a surjection, then $A$ is countable, so simply let $g=f^{-1}$ for all elements mapped to by $f$, and let $g(x)=a\in A$ (for one fixed element $a\in A$) for all elements that are not mapped.

Comment: inb4 axiom of choice comments

Comment: @Pedro: No need for them. There's no need for the axiom of choice to reverse a surjection from a well-ordered domain. (I mean, sure, this is an axiom of choice comment, but its sole existence is your fault with your comment above, so in some sense your comment was the reason why your comment was true. It's like predicting someone will be murdered, and then murdering them yourself...)

Comment: @AsafKaragila
Strange, would you weight murder and axiom of choice equivalently?

Comment: ellya, I just watch some TV show about a homicide detective. It was the first analogy that came to mind! :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila ahh.. good to know, I was worried for a minute..

Comment: I haven't killed anyone over using the axiom of choice. Yet. And if you believe the principle of induction, then it's probably going to stay this way, too. :-P